# Windows DLL & Dynamic Initialization Ordering

Tags: windows, dll, posix, dylib, shared-libraries

I have some question regarding dynamic initialization (i.e. constructors before main) and DLL link ordering - for both Windows and POSIX.

To make it easier to talk about, I'll define a couple terms:

> **Load-Time Libraries:** libraries which have been "linked" at compile
>   time such that, when the system loads my application, they get loaded
>   in automatically. (i.e. ones put in CMake's target_link_libraries
>   command).
>
> **Run-Time Libraries:** libraries which I load manually by dlopen or
>   equivalents. For the purposes of this discussion, I'll say that I only
>   ever manually load libraries using dlopen in main, so this should
>   simplify things.
>
> **Dynamic Initialization:** if you're not familiar with the C++ spec's
>   definition of this, please don't try to answer this question.

Ok, so let's say I have an application (MyAwesomeApp) and it links against a dynamic library (MyLib1), which in turn links against another library (MyLib2). So the dependency tree is:

MyAwesomeApp -> MyLib1 -> MyLib2

For this example, let's say MyLib1 and MyLib2 are both Load-Time Libraries.

What's the initialization order of the above? It is obvious that all static initialization, including linking of exported/imported functions (windows-only) will occur first... But what happens to Dynamic Initialization? I'd expect the overall ordering:

ALL import/export symbol linking
ALL Static Initialization
ALL of MyLib2's Dynamic Initialization
ALL of MyLib1's Dynamic Initialization
ALL of MyAwesomeApp's Dynamic Initialization
MyAwesomeApp's main() function

But I can't find anything in specs that mandate this. I DID see something with elf that hinted at it, but I need to find guarantees in specs for me to do something I'm trying to do.

Just to make sure my thinking is clear, I'd expect that library loading works very similarly to 'import in Python in that, if it hasn't been loaded yet, it'll be loaded fully (including any initialization) before I do anything... and if it has been loaded, then I'll just link to it.

To give a more complex example to make sure there isn't another definition of my first example that yields a different response:

MyAwesomeApp depends on MyLib1 & MyLib2
MyLib1 depends on MyLib2

I'd expect the following initialization:

ALL import/export symbol linking
ALL Static Initialization
ALL of MyLib2's Dynamic Initialization
ALL of MyLib1's Dynamic Initialization
ALL of MyAwesomeApp's Dynamic Initialization
MyAwesomeApp's main() function

I'd love any help pointing out specs that say this is how it is. Or, if this is wrong, any spec saying what REALLY happens!

Thanks in advance!

-Christopher

Comment: The relevant sentence from the standard would appear to be "Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable deﬁned in a diﬀerent translation unit."  Granted, I don't understand all of the rest of the paragraph, but I believe this means that there is no guarantee whether the dynamic initialization from MyLib1 will happen before or after that from MyLib2.

Comment: First off, that's primarily referring to within a library - not across a DLL boundary. Secondly, while the C++ standard cannot guarantee it across every possible target of C++, ELF and Microsoft's binary standards can, and that's what I'm after.

Comment: OK.  On Windows, any such guarantee (if possible) would have to be provided by the compiler, because Windows doesn't require compilers to do dynamic initialization in any particular way.  It does appear that the DLL entry points are called in the order you suggest, see [The NT DLL Loader: basic operation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgrier/archive/2005/06/18/430409.aspx) although it is not clear to me that this is contractual.  (It is nonetheless unlikely to change.)  So a compiler that does dynamic initialization in the most obvious way can be expected to behave as you suggest.

Comment: I've added a bounty as I think the question is interesting and it has not received much attention.  That said, it would seem strange to me for a compiler to provide a guarantee of this sort about load-time dynamic libraries given that there appears to be no such guarantee for statically linked modules, so my guess is that in most cases at least the behaviour will be undocumented and subject to change.  Hopefully the compiler experts can chime in here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the C++ standard mandates how dynamic linking works.

Having said that, Visual Studio ships with the C Runtime (aka CRT) source, and you can see where static initializers get run in dllcrt0.c.

You can also derive the relative ordering of operations if you think about what constraints need to be satisfied to run each stage:

1. Import/export resolution just needs .dlls.
2. Static initialization just needs .dlls.
3. Dynamic initialization requires all imports to be resolved for the .dll.

Step 1 & 2 do not depend on each other, so they can happen independently. Step 3 requires 1 & 2 for each .dll, so it has to happen after both 1 & 2.

So any specific loading order that satisfies the constraints above will be a valid loading order.

In other words, if you need to care about the specific ordering of specific steps, you probably are doing something dangerous that relies on implementation specific details that will not be preserved across major or minor revisions of the OS. For example, the way the loader lock works for .dlls has changed significantly over the various releases of Windows.

Comment: `Nothing in the C++ standard mandates how dynamic linking works.` In fact the standard doesn't know anything about dynamic linking. Besides, pretty good and precise answer.